# How can I get the length of a string to return back?

Tags: python, spyder

Trying to create a function that takes in one parameter named 'dna_seq' and it should return the number of characters in that string. Once it does that it's supposed to in return say "The provided DNA sequence contains x bases"

I've tried len() but that doesn't seem to do it? It returns none
For example, it should look like this:

```
>dna = 'GACCGGGTGTACATACACCCCTTCCACCTC'
>> seq_len(DNA)
>>>30
```

Instead, it returns saying None.

```
   # 2.
def seq_len(dna_seq):
    ''' add function description here '''
    seq_len.len('')
# 3.
# your code here.
print('The provided DNA sequence contains', seq_len, 'bases')
```

Comment: function should `return` something, just do `len(dna)`

Comment: `None` is the default value when you fail to `return` a value.  Please repeat your tutorial on functions.

Comment: If all you need is the length of a string, a function seems a bit heavy-handed for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to return the number of characters in the string.

```
def seq_len(dna_seq):
    return len(dna_seq)
```

Then you could print out:

```
print('The provided DNA sequence contains ', seq_len("string"), ' bases.')
```

Comment: That function is kinda useless.

Comment: Yea this worked out of all comments, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Learn about void functions vs functions with return statements: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Os0o3wzS_I

Void function:

```
>>> def function(param):
...     print('Function started.')
...     param*10
... 
>>> x = function(5)
Function started.
>>> print(x)
None
```

The function above does the calculation 5*10 when you call it during the assignment statement, but x will equal to None because you did not state what value the function should output or "return".

Function with a return statement:

```
>>> def function(param):
...     print('Function started.')
...     return param*10
... 
>>> x = function(5)
Function started.
>>> print(x)
50
```

Tip: Functions don't always have to have return functions. For example, you could have a function that prints out a string when called. But you need a return statement when you need it to output a value.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
def seq_len(dna_seq):
    print('The provided DNA sequence contains', len(dna_seq), 'bases')
```

Then you can call the function

```
dna = 'GACCGGGTGTACATACACCCCTTCCACCTC'
seq_len(dna) #result 'The provided DNA sequence contains', 30, 'bases'
```